# ES6: Using a class as a module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, graphql

I'm writing a simple application using a repository pattern, nodejs, graphql and sequelize. First here is my base repository:

```
import db from '../models';

export default class AbstractRepository {
  constructor (model, include) {
    if (new.target === AbstractRepository) {
      throw new TypeError('Cannot construct AbstractRepository instances directly.');
    }
    this.model = model;
    this.include = include;
  }
  static findAll () {
    return db[this.model].findAll({ include: this.include });
  }
}
```

Here is a repository that extends it:

```
import db from '../models';
import AbstractRepository from './AbstractRepository';

class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository {
  constructor () {
    super('User', [db.Clickwrap]);
  }
}

export default new UserRepository();
```

Lastly, here is where the UserRespository is used (there's more to this file, but this is the important part):

```
import UserRepository from '../../repositories/UserRepository';

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users (root, args, context) {
      return UserRepository.findAll();
    },
  },
};
```

When I run a simple graphql query in graphiql like this:

```
{
  users {
    id
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
_UserRepository2.default.findAll is not a function
```

Not sure what I'm missing that's causing this.

## Edit

I've updated my code so it's not exporting an instance anymore. Everything else has remained the same. Here's my new UserRepository file:

```
import db from '../models';
import AbstractRepository from './AbstractRepository';

class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository {
  constructor () {
    super('User', [db.Clickwrap]);
  }
}

export default UserRepository;
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
```

Comment: Why have you made `findAll` static? That is the reason.

Comment: [Never `export` a class instance!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39079929/1048572) Export the class itself instead.

Comment: @Bergi Never say never. Default export is great if a singleton is needed (not in this case). This doesn't mean that a class shouldn't be exported as named export too, at least for testing.

Comment: @estus If you want to export a singleton, you should be using an object literal instead of `class` syntax.

Comment: @Bergi This is a matter of taste to some degree, and I appreciate Occam's razor, but I don't think that it is applicable here. Generally speaking, classes are superior to object literals for singletons, just because of proper inheritance and [the performance of accessors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338289/object-descriptor-getter-setter-performance-in-recent-chrome-v8-versions) (a bummer but that's true). Any way, that's offtopic, since the class in the question doesn't look like it needs to be a singleton.

Comment: @Bergi (and everyone else) I changed my export, and now have a new error. I updated the post to reflect. Any more thoughts?

Comment: Found my issue. The error is coming from the `findAll` method in the AbstractRepository. `this.model` is undefined because I'm calling everything statically, thus never calling the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment above, I was going about it the wrong way. Once I did as suggested and exported the class instead of an instance of the class I got an undefined error that I thought meant `UserRepository` wasn't defined in my `user.js` file. However, the error was actually in my `findAll()` method in my `AbstractRepository` because `this.model` was never set up because I was trying to do everything with static, thus never calling the constructor. So I gave up the static nonsense and instantiated an instance of my `UserRepository`. So the `UserRepository` looks like it does in the Edit part of my original post. However The `AbstractRepository` now looks like this:

```
import db from '../models';

export default class AbstractRepository {
  constructor (model, include) {
    if (new.target === AbstractRepository) {
      throw new TypeError('Cannot construct AbstractRepository instances directly.');
    }
    this.model = model;
    this.include = include;
  }
  findAll () {
    return db[this.model].findAll({ include: this.include });
  }
}
```

And my user.js file looks like this:

```
import UserRepository from '../../repositories/UserRepository';

const userRepo = new UserRepository();
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users (root, args, context) {
      return userRepo.findAll();
    },
  },
};
```

Now everything works great. Thanks for steering me in the right direction everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Static functions are not callable on instances of class. See the last example on [MDN documentation on static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).

In your code, you're exporting an instance of `UserRepository`:

```
export default new UserRepository();
```

which you import later with the same name as class name:

```
import UserRepository from '../../repositories/UserRepository';
```

Now, when you do `UserRepository.findAll()`, you're invoking `findAll` function on an instance of `UserRepository` class. You imported that instance with the same name as the class name. You're not actually invoking the static function `findAll` on the class. Instead you're doing it on an instance.

As Bergi already suggested, just export the class:

```
export default UserRepository;
```

Comment: That would remove the error, but `findAll()` would fail nonetheless.

Comment: I did as Bergi suggested and now, as @zeroflagL says it still fails, just with a different error. See the updated post above for details. Thanks for the input so far.