# es6 classes with express.js, how to pass instance of class so that each route can access?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I have a class class defined to keep track of some dynamic data that will be updated during runtime. I want the instance of this class to be accessible by all routes I have defined in my application:

```
export default class Manager {
  constructor() {
    let self = this;
    self.table = [];
  }
  addEntity(obj){
    let self = this;
    self.table.push(obj);
  }
}
```

Let's say I run my app and some event happens. I then invoke `manager.addEntity(...some_event...);`.

`self.table` will then have a new element. I want to be able to have a route access this information by requesting the route's url, maybe `GET /api/table/`. Unfortunately I currently have no way of accessing the instance of the class.

Should I assign the reference to the instance of the class to a global variable? This is an anti-pattern and I'd like to avoid doing this if possible.

My server is defined using normal recommended code:

```
import http from 'http';
import { env, mongo, port, ip, apiRoot } from './config';
import api from './api';
import express from './services/express';
import mongoose from './services/mongoose';
import Manager from './lib/manager.js';

const app = express(apiRoot, api);

const server = http.createServer(app);

mongoose.connect(mongo.uri, { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

new Manager().initialize(server);

setImmediate(() => {
  server.listen(port, ip, () => {
    console.log(
      'Express server listening on http://%s:%d, in %s mode',
      ip,
      port,
      env,
    );
  });
});

export default app;
```

Comment: Sounds like you are indeed looking for a global variable. There's only one instance of your class for your whole application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether singleton class is justified or not is decided on per case basis.

It can be justified if the use of a class can provide certain benefits:

- a class may be instantiated multiple times, while there should exist default instance
- a class may be extended
- a class can provide syntactic or functional benefits (for instance, [drastic performance optimization for prototype chain in Node.js/V8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338289/object-descriptor-getter-setter-performance-in-recent-chrome-v8-versions))

If there's a chance that it has to be instantiated multiple times (nested applications, testing, etc.), it can be a class with default instance. This is naturally provided by JS modules, including ES modules:

```
export class Manager {
  constructor() {
    this.table = [];
  }
  addEntity(obj) {
    this.table.push(obj);
  }
}

export default new Manager();
```

Notice that `Manager` is exported in case there's a need to instantiate or extend it.

If this is not the case, then KISS principle can be applied, and plain object can be used instead:"

```
export default {
  table: [],
  addEntity(obj) {
    this.table.push(obj);
  }
};
```

KISS principle can be applied further; if pushing an object to the array is all that the class does, `addEntity` isn't very helpful. It can be omitted, so we end up with a single array.

In Express.js, application-wide variables are conventionally stored as [application settings](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set), so the variable (either the entire object or table array) could be stored and retrieved from application instance:

```
app.set('managed entities', []);
...
app.get('managed entities').push(...);
```

The requirement is to have access to application instance, so the code that uses `managed entities` setting should reside inside middleware function. On the other hand, this provides more flexibility. The setting can be overridden if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: **Refer to the comment by Bergi below as to why the answer I posted is a bad idea.**

--

Export a instance of that class that all the routes import. Instead maybe something like this (single instance pattern):

```
class Manager {
    ...
}

export default new Manager();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a new instance for each route that imports it?

Comment: Hm, according to this: https://k94n.com/es6-modules-single-instance-pattern -- it should work

Comment: Modules are only evaluated once, this ensures only one instance will be created/used

Comment: [Do not do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739499/1048572)! If you want singletons, don't use a `class`.

Comment: Using functional singleton works in @Bergi's link. We export the reference to the object so we are always using the same object when imported. Thanks.