# Performance implications of binding to simple fields vs. properties of objects vs. getters in Angular

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding

Is there any difference in performance when binding to simple fields (e.g. `[(ngModel)]="room"`) in comparison to binding to properties of objects? (e.g. `[(ngModel)]="lesson.room"`) If yes, why is that?

Concerning getters: Am I correct in my understanding that binding to getters/setters and e.g. one-way binding to functions is bad, because the function will be called every single detection cycle, without Angular being able to differentiate between situations where there was no change and situations where a change actually happened and an update of the view is in fact necessary? This should make getters the least performant option in this regard.

Comment: If you have multiple questions ask it in separate threads.

Comment: The questions are so tightly interlinked that I cannot justify asking a separate question @KrishnaMohan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no difference in performance, at least until `lesson` reference is changed. Even then the difference will be nonexistent because property access is very fast in JavaScript. It should be noticed that `room` is a property too.

If accessor method or property getter is bound, it will be called on every change detection cycle. It may be appropriate if function call isn't costly and/or change detection cycles aren't too dense. If they are dense, their amount can be reduced with `OnPush` change detection strategy.

For example, `{{ foobar }}` binding is ok:

```
get foobar() {
  return this.foo + this.bar;
}
```

And `{{ factorial(num) }}` binding may be costly, it can be refactored to pure pipe or be cached to a property on `num` change.

It should be noticed that there may be some caveats, e.g. property getter will suffer [performance penalty in Chrome/V8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338289/object-descriptor-getter-setter-performance-in-recent-chrome-v8-versions/42709301#42709301) if it isn't defined on a prototype, like:

```
lesson = { get room() {/*...*/} }
```

Depending on real performance impact, these concerns may be considered preliminary optimization.

Comment: You are talking about "dense" change detection cycles. Is there any way of influencing the density without changing the change detection strategy (or detaching the change detector)? As far as my understanding goes, Angular decides when a change detection is run: After x seconds, when typing, clicking etc.

Comment: Change detection cycle happens when change detection it is triggered in current zone. Yes, it will be triggered by DOM or other async events (as long as they happen in a zone). Pieces of code that are responsible for CD spam can be throttled/debounced or evaluated with zone `runOutsideAngular`. CD can also be (temporarily) switched off with ChangeDetectorRef `detach`.

Comment: Notice that Angular event bindings trigger CD, e.g. `(mousemove)=...` is a notable spammer. So it should be either be treated with `detach`, or event listener has to be set up manually and throttled, like `Observable.fromEvent(...).debounceTime(...)`. Again, this is preliminary optimization, unless proven otherwise.

Comment: I am using `@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])` and noticed this is probably the culprit of my performance issues. Apparently triggering change detection from HostListener events is neither affected by detaching the change detector nor by setting the detection strategy to `OnPush` for the relevant component. Any hint you can give me on (temporarily) avoiding HostListener events triggering change detection?

Comment: I see. Yes, HostListener will likely be a problem. It's same as suggested above, you have to set up a listener manually with `Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')` and debounce it or disable CD there with runOutsideAngular. `document` is available for DI as DOCUMENT provider.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight difference between

```
[(ngModel)]="room"
```

and

```
[(ngModel)]="lesson.room")
```

because in the former case change detection checks only if room is identical to the instance when it last checked and
in the later case it has to check `lession` and then `room`.

If `lession` is an object and `room` a normal property this won't really matter because such checks are extremely fast.

Function invocation is less performant than simple object idendity comparison, but it's not too bad. It depends how often change detection happens.
The most important parts are

- that the function returns the same value on subsequent calls (if there was no async execution in between) otherwise Angular recognizes this and throws the infamous "The expression has changed since it was last checked"
- that the function doesn't do expensive work by itself.

If these criterias are considered binding to functions is acceptable in some situations. It's just prone to get it wrong and therefore it's usually better to not use it until you fully understand how change detection works.

The best way to find out if it works for you is to create your own benchmarks for your concrete use case.

Comment: You are saying "it depends how often change detection happens". The number of change detection cycles cannot be influenced without changing the change detection cycle (or detaching the change detector), can it? So if I understand it correctly, the overhead of using getters/functions is the overhead of the function call itself plus any work/calculation the function does? This overhead should then be relevant for every single detection cycle.

Comment: "without changing the change detection cycle" should be "without changing the change detection strategy"

Comment: If there is no change propagated to a child component, then there won't be a change. For example you have `@Input() a:string; b:string;` and `<child [prop]="b"></child>` with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the `child` component, then change detection in the child component will only run if you change `b`. If you change the input in the parent to ``@Input() set a(value:string) { if(value.prop this.b.prop) { this.b = value; this.cdRef.detectChanges(); };` then change detection on `<child>` will only run when `value.prop differs from `this.b.prop` (or other events that cause change ...

Comment: ... detection in components with `OnPush`.

Comment: So what's the problem with changing the change detection strategy?

Comment: There is no problem, just asking out of curiosity and understanding. So did I understand the overhead issue correctly? Using a simple field, Angular carries out an identity comparison every cycle, using a getter, the function is called every cycle (function call overhead) and the return value is then compared to the previous value analogously to simple fields (i.e. identity comparison), correct?