# How to define a property alias in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
let obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'src', {get: () => 'hello'});
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'alias1', {get: () => this['src']});
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'alias2', {get: this['src']});
console.log(obj.src);
console.log(obj.alias1);
console.log(obj.alias2);
```

outputs:

```
hello
undefined
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this` in arrow function is not what you think it is, use regular function expression instead. Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is always helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions), or [a wider explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch).

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'alias1', {get() { return this['src']}});`

Comment: Keep in mind that in V8, [own property accessors are about 14x slower than property accessors in `__proto__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48893360/1541563).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't bind the same `this` that you're expecting. In your cases, `this` refers to the global object. You can test this easily by changing your second line to:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'alias1', { get: () => { console.log(this) } });  // ==> Window
```

You'll need to change it to something like these:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'alias1', { get: () => obj.src });
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'alias2', { get: function () { return this.src } });
```

---

Live Example:

```js
let obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'src', {get: () => 'hello'});
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'alias1', {get: () => obj['src']});
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'alias2', {get: function () { return this.src }});
console.log(obj.src);
console.log(obj.alias1);
console.log(obj.alias2);
```

Comment: You forgot `{ get () { return this.src } }`, which in my opinion is the most readable option.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this['src']
```

must be

```
obj["src"]
```

or even

```
this.obj["src"]
```

As the context inside an arrow function is the one it was declared in (`window` in this case) not the object it is part of.