# Use Value in "export const" twice as variable

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export const foobar = {
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: this.foo
};
```

It wont work its: "undefined"

how can I access it?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible, but this seems strange. What is your use-case?

Comment: And `this` will be pointing to `window` object, so `bar` will be `undefined`. as there is no `window.foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your exported const `foobar`, `this` represent the context which owns the constant and which is `global\window`, So you get the value as `undefined`.

You have to create a new scope which is owned by your constant, which can be achieved by creating a `function` and assigning to `bar` property. Like below :

```
export const foobar = {
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: function(){
        return this.foo;
    }
};
```

now `this` will hold the `foobar` constant context and you will able to access prop  `foo`, by calling `foobar.bar()`(should return 'hello')

Answer (score 1):

As far a I know, you can't, at least not like you're trying to do it. You can't use `this`, because you're not inside a class, so it points to the global context (if any, or `undefined`) and the other only option would be to use `foobar` itself, like this:

```
const foobar = {
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: foobar.foo
}
```

But this won't work, either, because, until the statement is finished, `foobar`  is not defined, so you get an error.

I am afraid the only way is:

```
const foobar = {
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: undefined
}
foobar.bar = foobar.foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers already mention, `this` was used incorrectly. It refers to same `this` context as in the scope `foobar` variable was defined. It is `undefined` when the script runs in strict mode.

In order to refer `foo` property, `bar` can be defined as a pair of getter/setter functions:

```
export const foobar = {
    foo: 'hello',
    get bar() {
      return this.foo;
    },
    set bar(v) {
      this.foo = v;
    }
};
```

A setter can be omitted in case it's a constant that isn't supposed to be modified.

Notice that descriptors suffer from [performance penalty in plain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338289/object-descriptor-getter-setter-performance-in-recent-chrome-v8-versions/42709301#42709301) in V8 (Chrome, Node.js, etc), in performance-critical places it's beneficial to define a descriptor on object prototype, e.g. with `class` syntax.